# HBase region split unexpected, each region size less than 1g

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hbase, apache-phoenix

The `hbase.hregion.max.filesize` is 10g.

The split policy is `SteppingSplitPolicy`.

The table was created by phoenix with `salt_buckets = 6`.

According to source code of `SteppingSplitPolicy`:

```java
  protected long getSizeToCheck(final int tableRegionsCount) {
    return tableRegionsCount == 1  ? this.initialSize : getDesiredMaxFileSize();
  }
```

The region should be split when region size becomes larger than 10g (because the tableRegionsCount is 6).

However the table was split into 18 regions with total size 7.62 GB now.

```
StorefileSize(7.62 GB)  Num.Storefiles(34)
212 MB                  1
255 MB                  1
830 MB                  3
213 MB                  1
482 MB                  1
601 MB                  4
213 MB                  1
354 MB                  1
...                     ...
```

How can I find what triggered a region split?

### Jul 4 update

Also tried `ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy`, the result was the same.

This is test env, all components are apache bundle, and the cpu/memory resources are shortage.

The pre-production env works well with `SteppingSplitPolicy` which is HDP bundle.

Checked the most of configuration are the same.

I'm busy on the other works now, I'll continue look into it when I'm free.